# How to reference and refresh a QueryTable in Excel 2016 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm trying to refresh a query on a cell change, however I can't figure out how to reference the query.

My code: `Sheets("Roster Query").QueryTables(0).Refresh`

Just errors out with:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

I have a sheet named "Roster Filter" that has  query table I want to refresh. How can I get that QueryTable and refresh it?

Edit: Also tried:

```
For Each qt In Sheets("Roster Query").QueryTables
    qt.Refresh
Next
```

This does not error out, but the query is not refreshed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Query tables are a relic of older versions of Excel, before *tables* were a thing. Not sure how to even create one in Excel 2007+.

If you added your QT via the *Data/Get External Data* Ribbon menu, what you added was actually a `ListObject`.

I tested this on `Sheet1`, adding a simple query - Excel created the `ListObject` for me:

[image: Excel creates a ListObject]

In the *immediate pane*, I get these results:

```
?Sheet1.QueryTables.Count
 0
?Sheet1.ListObjects.Count
 1
```

And I can reproduce your exact same error:

```
Sheet1.QueryTables(0).Refresh 'runtime error 1004
```

The error is simply outrageously misleading, that's all - it should really be an *index out of bounds*.

The solution is to refresh the `ListObject` instead:

```
Sheet1.ListObjects(1).Refresh 'works
```

You can access the *underlying* `QueryTable` object via the `ListObject`, too:

```
?Sheet1.ListObjects(1).QueryTable.CommandText 'gives you the query
```

Comment: I'm using Power Query, does this not create a query table? The Excel documentation is fragmented all over the place, it's hard to make heads or tails of it. I'll have to look at the list object bit. Thanks.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell If you can type a *table formula* in it, it's a `ListObject`. A `QueryTable` (in Excel 97-2003) looked like a plain range, except you could refresh it. What do you get for `?Sheets("Roster Query").QueryTables.Count`?

Comment: That does the trick! Now to ask a question on how to prevent excel from hanging if there are functions updating when I try and refresh the table through VBS

Comment: @DouglasGaskell try `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` (well, in VBScript that would be `yourExclAppInstance.Calculation = -4135`), assuming the Excel type library is late-bound.

Comment: @TylerH sure, but *index out of bounds* would point me to the off-by-one indexing much faster than error 1004.. anyway, all moot with ListObjects =)

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing an error because the [`.Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838985.aspx) method is base 1, not base 0

For example, this worked for me in Excel 2016:

```
Sheets("Roster Query").QueryTables(1).Refresh
```

So if you only have one QueryTable, it would be `.QueryTables(1)`.

Comment: That's rather awkward, given a collection class' default member is typically its `Item` property, which makes `.QueryTables(1)` completely equivalent to `.QueryTables.Item(1)`. What does `Sheets("Roster Query").QueryTables.Count` return? 1? Are you using Power Query?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I absolutely agree; it is rather awkward. And, to be clear, I don't think this approach is necessarily better than the one you provided, but it does work and I think solves the OP's issue. The answer to your question is 1, which is correct in my example setup.

Comment: I couldn't repro, but I'm on Excel 2010, so have an upvote... removing the explicit `.Item` call causes OP's error? (sorry to insist, I'm just kinda flabbergasted lol)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Sorry, forgot your second question; no, I'm not using Power Query. I created the QueryTable via VBA. Well, I thought removing the `.Item` caused the error, but no! Removing the `.Item` call is not causing an issue. But base 0 definitely is. I'll update my answer.